# Android DatePicker components order

Tags: android, datepicker, locale, date-format

I made a custom `DatePicker` that extends the android `DatePicker` UI component. I needed this to make possible the visibility option for each `DatePicker`'s view component(day,month and year). 
I made this possible by hiding the views from `DatePicker` by its index.

I get the index of each component by getting the date format order like this `DateFormat.getDateFormatOrder(context)` , this returns a char array like {m, d, y} so I can get the order of the `DatePicker` components and hide them..

The problem I run into is that on some devices the `DatePicker` position its components by the selected locale of the user and not by the selected date format.

How can I get the `DatePicker`'s components order? Or how I can figure out that `DatePicker` will position its components by locale or date format?

Note that I am developing this on Android API level 2.1++ and I would prefer not to make my own `DatePicker` so I can preserve the android `DialogPicker` UI theme.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And unfortunately the answer is: I had to develop my own DatePicker and now everything works fine